# antlr error in (CommonTree)parser.javaSource() line

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have used ANTLR to parse Java code and everything works well. But the problem is getting the following error when I run it in on a Mac:

```
javac -cp antlrworks-1-1.4.3.jar *.java
Main.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method javaSource()
location: class JavaParser
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.javaSource().getTree();
                                            ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java grammar you are using does not have a rule called `javaSource`, so no method with that name exists in the generated code. Some other Java grammars I have seen use `compilationUnit`, but without seeing your grammar there's no way to tell you exactly how to fix this.

Comment: i used this one: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g
 now, I have tried to use another Java grammar but does not work with me and has 100 errors rather than one ,, i need to generate AST for my Java code ,, what shall i do ?

Comment: @CuteAlsharif, Sam (280Z28) answered your question: the grammar you're using does not have a `javaSource` rule (and therefor, there is no `javaSource` method in the generated parser). Try to use `compilationUnit` instead. But realize that the grammar you're referring to does *not* generate an AST. That mean that casting to a `CommonTree` will throw an exception!